# Azure Front Door Is Not Maintaining Custom Domain in Browser

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

Domain in Azure Front Door:
`www.foobar.com`

Azure Web Apps:
`foobar-web`
`foobar-api`

I would like to be able to have `www.foobar.com` pull up the web app `foobar-web` and utilize `/api` in the url to access the web app `foobar-api`.

`www.foobar.com` -> `foobar-web`
`www.foobar.com/api` -> `foobar-api`

I have a backend pool setup for each and route rules setup. Each time I try navigating to `www.foobar.com/api` the url in the browser changes to `foobar-api.azurewebsites.net/api`, but if I navigate to `www.foobar.com` in pulls up the `foobar-web` web app while maintaining the `www.foobar.com` domain in the browser.

Is there a setting in Azure Front Door that I am missing or something that needs to be configured in the web app or source code to maintain the domain?

The web app is a C# ASP.NET Web API 2 solution.

Thank you in advance for any answers/suggestions.

Comment: I think my answer is a easy way to solve your issue. I have try to use two different webapps in front door, it always have some problem, maybe need use other services like `application gateway`.

Answer (score 0):

**Newest**

The API routing rules for APIs require you to define your own in the project. The examples shown here are only sample code.

My settings in front door.

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

After my testing, I used Virtual applications to fulfill your needs.

[image]

The screenshot below is my project structure.

[image]

Before you deploy your app, you need to modify `.csproj` file.  Generally, you just need to modify `foobar-api` project, if deploy failed you can modify both two projects.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>foobar_web</RootNamespace>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can deploy it, I create `test/aa` in `foobar-api` project.

*Web page*

[image]

*Index of Virtual applications*

[image]

*Api test in Virtual applications*

[image]

After creating the front door service, after the configuration is complete.

*Web*

[image]

*Api*

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jason Pan. This is not exactly the setup that I have. The setup I have puts the web and api on separate web apps.

Comment: @Jared You can add new pool and rule to test it. Front door can support it. I also will try it and update my answer later.

Comment: @Jared After my attempts, you can try to use a webapp like me. There are some problems with multiple web apps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/troubleshoot-app-service-redirection-app-service-url