# Vue Frontend and Express backend on same Azure web app Service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have built a web app that has a Vue front-end and an express back-end.

I am trying to host these on an Azure Web App Service but I am a complete novice with Azure.
I have gotten the web app working fine when I place the Client side in one web app and the Server side in a different one.
I want to have both running *in the same web app.*
From researching online it seems that I need to go to:

```
my web app-> configuration-> path mappings ->Virtual applications and directories.
```

I created a new application with Virtual Path "/app" and physical path "site\app".
I deployed (using visual studio code) my back-end to my azure web app and thus this sits inside wwwroot.
In filezilla I create a new folder in the site directory called "app" and paste in my built Vue client side.
However, when I try to navigate to [www.myapp.azurewebsites.net/app](http://www.myapp.azurewebsites.net/app) I am not presented with the expected Vue index.html rather a 404. If I just navigate to [www.myapp.azurewebsites.net/](http://www.myapp.azurewebsites.net/) I get the default route from the server side as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a webapp, please choose `Windows` operating environment, because currently choosing `Linux` **does not support Virtual Application and directories**.

**The directory structure** should be like below.

[image]

**Setting in portal.**

[image]

For more details, you can [refer my answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337016/azure-front-door-is-not-maintaining-custom-domain-in-browser/62592372#62592372).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using windows but I am still confused. How can I deploy the API backend into that specific directory? I am using the Azure addon for visual studio code (maybe I should not be using this?). When I click to deploy from here it does not give me an option for where exactly to put the backend, instead all of it is placed into the wwwroot directory?

Comment: First, I think the operations of virtual applications are not convenient. Maybe you can deploy you main apps by vscode, and deploy virtual application by FTP. 

Second, I suggest you set your backend api project as main app, and put your vue project as virtual application. So you can monitor and analysis  the application .

Comment: @micheal You can use vscode to deploy your backend project, and use FTP tools to upload your frontend project.