# Deploy node.js server and angular app to azure web service

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Angular app (9.1.4) and a node.js server application (12.14.1). My files are currently configured like this:

```
MyApp
- package.json
- angular.json
- server
  - server.js
- src
  - app
  - asserts
  - environments
  - angular html/css/ts
- node_modules
```

In order to runt his locally I have to run `node server.js` in one cmd prompt and `ng serve` in another. I hope to deploy this project to Azure but am not sure how to set this up so that it can run in a single app service. So:

1. How do I run the server (node.js) and the app (angular) via the same command locally?
2. Once I have this setup locally, what (if anything) needs to be changed in order to run in Azure?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are the startup ports of your project, front-end angular project and back-end node service in the same configuration file?

1. If yes, then you can [execute multiple commands](https://itnext.io/4-solutions-to-run-multiple-node-js-or-npm-commands-simultaneously-9edaa6215a93) by modifying the script in the `package.json` file.
2. Because only `443` and `80` ports are supported in azure web app. If the port configuration of the two projects is not the same, it may run normally locally.

For example, the ng project is `7001`, and the server project is `7002`, deployed to the azure web app, according to the `process.env.PORT`  parameters, it will the port conflicts and the project cannot be started.

***So if it is the second case, how to deal with:***

You can use virtual applications to deploy your applications separately. For more details, you can [see my answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346246/vue-frontend-and-express-backend-on-same-azure-web-app-service/63350507#63350507).

Comment: This is helpful! I am now running multiple commands locally and launching the server and the app at the same time. But how do I do this in my azure web app? How do I set this startup command? I used FTP to deploy the angular app, but the server doesn't seem to be running as I can't hit any of the APIs. I think it may be related to the port? I just have it hardcoded right now to 3000, which is none of the ports you mentioned above. How do I configure this?

Comment: @alanafrankly You can add start command in portal with `npx serve -s`.

Comment: @alanafrankly What I mean is, although your project is divided into front-end and back-end, you still need to use it in your coding, such as `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000); `, the backend is set to `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);`, while `443` and `80`, they are running in azure, `process.env.PORT` The default value.

Comment: @alanafrankly You cannot hard-code the configuration port value. Just set it like `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)` .

Comment: @alanafrankly Have you used a virtual application?