# Azure CI/CD setup to build + serve React build directory from Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, azure-web-app-service, devops

Using Web apps in Azure, and Github CI/CD, is there a way to deploy an Express/React app as one application, where the deployment process takes care of building client/React code? Here is my directory setup:

- server.js (this is express logic)
- package.json
- client/ (client directory containing React source code)

I have server.js setup to serve a static client/build/index.html file. However, I'm not sure how to create that build directory within CI/CD. I'm currently just running `npm run build` locally and then pushing the build directory to my repo, but I'd preferably like deployment to take care of running `npm run build`.

[Article 1 in Medium](https://medium.com/@chrisjr06/creating-mern-stack-app-and-hosting-in-microsoft-azure-using-create-react-app-w-continuous-4acef0c87e71) suggests changing the start script at the root level of server, but this does not work with Azure.

[Article 2 from Medium](https://medium.com/@tuna.sogut/how-to-deploy-a-mern-stack-app-to-azure-via-continuous-integration-a3a551526e26)  suggests running `npm run build` locally, pushing that directory to CI/CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your expected goal.**

> Using Web apps in Azure, and Github CI/CD, is there a way to deploy an Express/React app as one application.

**I suggest you, the front-end react project and the back-end express project, it is better to completely separate.**

**The reason:**

Even if the two projects are placed in the same directory, when they are essentially running, they are still running two ports separately.

***Reference tutorial:***

[How to create a React frontend and a Node/Express backend and connect them](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/)

[Building a React app with a Express back-end in the same project with external access to a MySQL database](https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-react-app-with-a-express-back-end-in-the-same-project-with-external-access-to-a-mysql-e06ef83c257d)

From the current mainstream point of view, it is better to completely separate the front and back projects and not put them in a project structure.

**My advice:**

You don't want create two webapp services, you can use `Virtual Apllications` in windows platform. You can deloy your express project by github. But your react project maybe need choose another way to deploy, like `zip` etc.

As of now, I haven't seen the use of github to deploy virtual applications.

***You can refer to my answer in the following post.***

[How to deploy a Flask+React application to Azure Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982446/how-to-deploy-a-flaskreact-application-to-azure-web-service/63985149#63985149)

[Vue Frontend and Express backend on same Azure web app Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346246/vue-frontend-and-express-backend-on-same-azure-web-app-service/63350507#63350507)

[React.js - How to deploy client and server independently or together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997169/react-js-how-to-deploy-client-and-server-independently-or-together/64020730#64020730)