# React.js - How to deploy client and server independently or together?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, deployment, production

I have a react.js website with a backend in Node/express hosted on Azure, right now the project is monolithic, every time I do a change in the front or backend everything is redeployed in production. What I would like to achieve is to be able to deploy the frontend and the backend independently from one another whenever I push a change on github, but also if they are both affected deploy them together to avoid inconsistencies. Do you know some best practices or services to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: It is recommended that the front and back ends of the project should be separated, so the project structure will be clear and easy to expand and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The git deployment method of Azure app services is simple. However, as long as we modify the file, all deployment commands will be executed and the entire deployment process will start. This cannot be changed.

Based on your description, I probably know that your project is a fusion of front and back ends, without separation of front and back ends. So I guess, you want to use the same app services for the front-end app and the back-end app.

[image]

[image]

So I suggest that you still separate the front and back ends of the project. This is the mainstream. It is also convenient for later maintenance and expansion. If you just want to use a webapp service, you can use a webapp based on the windows environment, and just use a virtual application. In this way, the update program can be completely separated without any impact.

***Note that at present I found that the virtual application does not support the react project and has raised a support ticket to confirm. If have any progress, I will tell you.***