# Hosting a sub ASP application in a nodejs express application in azure

Tags: node.js, web-config, azure-web-app-service

**Q1)** I have my main app built with nodejs express. I have a sub-app made using asp.net and I want to host that as a virtual application within my main app. Is there any way I can do this?

Currently, my nodejs are treating the call `https://localhost:5000/mysite1` as a directory and giving a 404 error.

My folder structure looks like...

```
index.html
server.js
scripts
web.config (*)
----- mysite1
      |----- bin
      |----- Controllers
      |----- Pages
      |----- Scripts
      |----- web.config (**)
```

**Q2** *In the long run, I'd like to take the app to Azure App Services and host it there. The runtime stack would be Node 12 LTS. Is this possible in Azure?*

My web.config file for nodejs app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^cot" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>



        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
    
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Update**

Server.js routing

```
..
....
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/auth', authRouter);  
....
..
```

Answer (score 0):

The virtual application directory structure should look like this.

```
wwwroot
  |----- index.html
  |----- server.js
  |----- scripts
  |----- web.config (*)
mysite1
  |----- bin
  |----- Controllers
  |----- Pages
  |----- Scripts
  |----- web.config (**)
```

For more details, you can check my answer in below post.

[**How to deploy a Flask+React application to Azure Web Service**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982446/how-to-deploy-a-flaskreact-application-to-azure-web-service/63985149#63985149)

[**React.js - How to deploy client and server independently or together?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997169/react-js-how-to-deploy-client-and-server-independently-or-together/64020730#64020730)

Comment: I tried doing the above structure but my server.js was getting all the calls being made to mysite1. So i'm guessing I have to change something in my web.config or in my server.js to allow that to happen? I've provided a snippet of my routes in server.js

Comment: @user7278236 You should use `virtual` path to send your http request. And this is another question. You can google it.